# How to impute a mean value where a feature is null?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to fill in a mean value where a feature is null.

I've tried:

```
# Let's impute other NAs with mean value
for f in data:
   if data[f].isnull().sum() / data.shape[0] < threshold: np.isnan(data[f]) = data[f].mean()
```

...which raises an error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

I've also tried

```
data[f][np.isnan(data[f])] = data[f].mean()
```

but that's even a bigger mess.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.fillna` to fill the nan's directly.
It creates a dataframe replacing `nan` with value specified in the parentheses.

`df.fillna(df.mean())` will return the new dataframe, so you will have to write  `df=df.fillna(df.mean())` to keep it.

Comment: It takes terribly long time to compute.

Comment: Well, try to group your data if it's too large. You can try: `df = df.groupby(['id']).fillna(df.mean())`